# How can I post in Facebook wall programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm very new to Facebook (yeah, I'm the only one) but I'd like to publish messages in the wall programmatically using Python.

What do I need to do to achieve that? I'm very confused. I have seen that most question about this are focused on how to let an app interact in some way with Facebook, but I'd like to post as if I were a simple user (a user which happens to "own" that particular Facebook page). Do I really need to go and create an app? (By the way, I'm having problems even with that... it tells me that my account seems fake or invalid even after I validated it via SMS). I imagine that there is a simpler way, introducing my credentials, using a `POST` request but I haven't read something similar.

I would have thought [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing) is what I needed, but it leads to a page to create an app.

Some pointers?

By the way, I got a token via a publish_stream permission in the Graph API Explorer (using the extended permissions tab). Seems like this permission doesn't have expiration date but it's not recommended. Is there a better choice for a token?.

Thanks

Comment: Forgetting python for the moment, I wonder are you asking specifically for facebook, or generally how one might automate sending POST headers without a browser?

Comment: Facebook but either way, it probably involves using Facebook API.

Comment: facebook api would be the "right" way to do it, but you can probably hack it together with curl, i'll give you an example in a sec

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Yeah, I'm still searching for an example using the API but I haven't found anything in Python.

Comment: I think I know what you're after: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?method=POST&message=hi%20there!&access_token=MY_TOKEN. Right? Even so, I would appreciate your CURL example. By the way, do tokens have expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is a bit trickier than other sites it would appear.

While watching the POST tab under NET in Firebug, while logging in, I see the following POST parameters:

```
charset_test    €,´,€,´,水,Д,Є
default_persistent  1
email   myusername
lgnjs   1340241652
lgnrnd  182050_CuPx
locale  en_US
lsd AVqwALVx
pass    mypassword
persistent  1
timezone    240
```

I don't yet know what `lsd` paramater is, but I did find out what the lgnrnd was by viewing the source of the login page before I logged in.  It appears to be there to make it more difficult to automate authentication.

You first want your script to scrape that login page for that value, store it in a variable.  Then, a cURL example would be something like:

```
curl -L "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" \
  --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies.txt \
  --data-urlencode "email=myusername" \
  --data-urlencode "lgnrnd=$lgnrnd" \
  --data-urlencode "pass=mypassword"
  and so forth, with all the parameters...
```

This is untested of course, and I don't know what some of those parameter values are yet, but you should get the idea from that.  You could probably use a python module like Beautiful Soup or something to apply the above basic concept.

Then you would do the same thing, watching the NET tab to find the parameters sent when you post to your facebook wall, and put it all together.

Note that I'm storing and using cookies with curl's --cookie-jar option.  You will need a way to save and use cookies with the request as well, which is why I showed that.

Hope that helps you get started anyway..

Comment: Just realized something.  For the lgnrnd value, I believe you're going to need to store that value "on the fly", meaning, you can't grab it ahead of time, then login again, as it regenerates on refresh.  Make sense?  One of these days I'll test this, and I'll try this myself, and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a good start. I found another way using the API (although, I don't know whether I'm using it as intended). I will post it as an answer ready to receive comments.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?.

```
import urllib2, urllib
parameters = {}
parameters['access_token'] = MY_TOKEN
parameters['message'] = 'Hello world'
target = 'https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ID/feed'

parameters = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
handler = urllib2.urlopen(target, parameters)
while True:
    if handler.code < 400:
        print handler.read() # Gets post_id
        break
    elif handler.code >= 400:
        print 'Error' # :-(
        break
```

Are there problems with this? Maybe a better way? Comments?

Thanks